# How do I create a new URL for a users confirmation page, without first manually adding it to my server.

Tags: php, html

After browsing through static pages and paying, I'd like for the user to see a confirmation page at .com/confirmation/randomkey. How do I create the random key after payment if I didn't create it before by manually adding a php file to my server. There's no point in creating the URL before since I don't know who's gonna purchase and every single one should be unique.

Comment: The random value should be a _parameter_ passed to a pre-determined file, not the name of the file itself. If you want to use the URL format mentioned in your question (as opposed to a querystring), you can use URL rewriting

Comment: exactly the SAME way you'd have `example.com/store/prod/123` work...

Comment: How? For example.com/Store/prod/123 to work I would create a store folder and prod folder and 123 php file. What I want is to plug a random variable into the end of the URL...(a file that doesn't actually exist).. and display the information for that particular order

Comment: Seems like using the parameter variable will be easiest.. going to try adding the param, passing it to file and loading the info from that variable

Answer (score 0):

You can user SEO-Friendly Links in order to rewrite the URL.
Then you will be able to handle the randomkey as a parameter and do not need for each user a individual page.

Example:
`www.example.com/confirmation/randomkey` will be rewritten to `www.example.com/?a=confirmation&key=randomkey`
This is often used by MVC: e.g. the first parameter (confirmation) will be the controller and depending on the parameter (randomkey) the contentwill be different. In this case, you will not need static sites.

Comment: Seems like what I'm looking for.. so basically it's sent to the confirmation page and the confirmation page will take the key and adjust the information shown.. what file do I need to adjust in order for this to happen..

Comment: Basicly you will only have an index.php Everything will be controlled by the PHP get parameter. If you want to use static files, you can include them by taking the parameters as filenames, but i will not recomend this. Just search for some MVC Frameworks like Zend etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I need apologise as I misread your question. I can see one of the answers briefly touched on it so I will explain a little more in depth whilst utilising my answer for the random key.

So a the moment (judging by your comments and question) you have static pages but you would like the confirmation page to be dynamic.

Your best having an `index.php` in the root of `.com/confirmation/`. This can have your static confirmation page HTML along with the PHP content.

**.com/confirmation/index.php?key=123456**

```
<?php 

   $key = $_GET['key'] //Get key from URL which 123456

   //Check if Key is set or else redirect them somewhere else

   if (!isset($key)) {

          header('Location: http://www.foo.com/foo.php' );       

   }


?>
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
   <p> Confirmation Key: <?php echo $key; //Print confirmation key to screen ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This could also be achieved by passing data using sessions which means no data is passed via URL. This can be picked up in `$_SESSION` variable which can be accessed from page to page. By doing this, you would NOT need to pass the variable in a URL, you would just need to generate it from the page before confirmation and send the confirmation key. Sessions last until the browser has been closed so it's not like cookies where you can set the expiry of the data.

**Page before confirmation**

```
<?php

//Start a session 
session_start();

//add to session variable
$key = $_SESSION['key'] = "Your KEY";

?>
```

**.com/confirmation/index.php**

```
<?php 

   session_start(); //Needs to start before session data can be read

   $key = $_SESSION['key'] //Data is queried from server NOT URL.

   //Check if Key is set or else redirect them somewhere else

   if (!isset($key)) {

          header('Location: http://www.foo.com/foo.php' );       

   }


?>
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
   <p> Confirmation Key: <?php echo $key; //Print confirmation key to screen ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: Hopefully this will help.